# "documents you sent me" or "documents that you have sent me"

Tags: difference, tense, sentence-choice

Which is the correct sentence?

1. I filled out the **documents you sent me**.

OR

2. I filled out the **documents that you have sent me**.

Could somebody explain me why first or second sentence is correct?

Comment: They're both grammatical in context.

Comment: The subordinator "that" is omissible in your example.